# Amazon Ec2 Automatically Create New Instance On Event

Tags: amazon-ec2

How could I do this on Amazon AWS: Automatically create a new instance on a certain Elastic IP and close another when X happens, in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 things, Simple bash script command + Amazon AMI API to launch new instance.
Let me give you the algorithm that how it will work then you can write it in bash+API commands.

if DB Event
then
Create ami
Associate Elastic IP with AMI
Turn on AMI

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate [CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), the AWS auto-scaling service.